# Set variable to input value (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, input

So, I have the following code, and it's not working, and I'm not sure why. Any suggestions?

HTML:

```
<input type="number" placeholder="#" id="lineSpace"/>

<br/><br/><button id="go">update text!</button>
```

JavaScript (jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var lineSpace = $("#lineSpace").val();

$("#go").click(function(){
alert("LINE SPACE: "+lineSpace+"");
});
```

This was a test to see if my variable was being gathered, but it seems not. The alert appears but simply says "LINE SPACE: ", without placing the variable after it. When I define the like this `var lineSpace = "random number";`(which is no use to me, as I need a value that is entered from the user-side), however, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are assigning lineSpace when the page loads, and it's obviously blank then.

Move `var lineSpace = $("#lineSpace").val();` into your click handler (above the `alert()` function call).